NVIDIA Server Driver metapackage (nvidia-driver-550-server) fix failed (Ubuntu 22.04)
I have a problem with my graphics driver under Ubuntu 22.04 and with the official NVIDIA driver. Due to an error, I have installed the server version. There seems to have been a conflict and I cannot resolve it. The NVIDIA drivers cannot be removed or another driver installed using either remove or purge. I also cannot switch to another driver, as apt always informs me of the missing dependencies and then cancels. Unfortunately, I have too little idea how to identify the cause of the problem and would be grateful for any further ideas.
sudo apt-get upgrade       
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-driver-550-server : Depends: libnvidia-gl-550-server (= 550.54.15-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) but it is not installed
                            Depends: nvidia-dkms-550-server (<= 550.54.15-1)
                            Depends: nvidia-dkms-550-server (>= 550.54.15)
                            Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-550-server (<= 550.54.15-1) but it is not installed
                            Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-550-server (>= 550.54.15) but it is not installed
                            Depends: nvidia-kernel-source-550-server (= 550.54.15-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) but it is not installed
                            Depends: libnvidia-compute-550-server (= 550.54.15-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) but it is not installed
                            Depends: libnvidia-extra-550-server (= 550.54.15-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) but it is not installed
                            Depends: nvidia-compute-utils-550-server (= 550.54.15-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) but it is not installed
                            Depends: libnvidia-decode-550-server (= 550.54.15-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) but it is not installed
                            Depends: libnvidia-encode-550-server (= 550.54.15-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) but it is not installed
                            Depends: nvidia-utils-550-server (= 550.54.15-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) but it is not installed
                            Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-550-server (= 550.54.15-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) but it is not installed
                            Depends: libnvidia-cfg1-550-server (= 550.54.15-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) but it is not installed
                            Depends: libnvidia-fbc1-550-server (= 550.54.15-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) but it is not installed
                            Recommends: libnvidia-compute-550-server:i386 (= 550.54.15-0ubuntu0.22.04.2)
                            Recommends: libnvidia-decode-550-server:i386 (= 550.54.15-0ubuntu0.22.04.2)
                            Recommends: libnvidia-encode-550-server:i386 (= 550.54.15-0ubuntu0.22.04.2)
                            Recommends: libnvidia-fbc1-550-server:i386 (= 550.54.15-0ubuntu0.22.04.2)
                            Recommends: libnvidia-gl-550-server:i386 (= 550.54.15-0ubuntu0.22.04.2)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

and if I try to fix the problem or remove the drive completely In get something like:
sudo apt --fix-broken install                                                                      
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-cfg1-550-server libnvidia-compute-550-server libnvidia-decode-550-server libnvidia-encode-550-server libnvidia-extra-550-server libnvidia-fbc1-550-server libnvidia-gl-550-server nvidia-compute-utils-550-server nvidia-dkms-550-server nvidia-firmware-550-server-550.54.15 nvidia-kernel-common-550-server nvidia-kernel-source-550-server nvidia-utils-550-server xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-550-server
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libnvidia-cfg1-550 libnvidia-compute-550:i386 libnvidia-compute-550 libnvidia-decode-550:i386 libnvidia-decode-550 libnvidia-encode-550:i386 libnvidia-encode-550 libnvidia-extra-550 libnvidia-fbc1-550:i386 libnvidia-fbc1-550 nvidia-compute-utils-550 nvidia-dkms-550-open nvidia-firmware-550-550.54.15 nvidia-kernel-common-550 nvidia-kernel-source-550-open nvidia-utils-550 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-550
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-cfg1-550-server libnvidia-compute-550-server libnvidia-decode-550-server libnvidia-encode-550-server libnvidia-extra-550-server libnvidia-fbc1-550-server libnvidia-gl-550-server nvidia-compute-utils-550-server nvidia-dkms-550-server nvidia-firmware-550-server-550.54.15 nvidia-kernel-common-550-server nvidia-kernel-source-550-server nvidia-utils-550-server xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-550-server
0 upgraded, 14 newly installed, 17 to remove and 38 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/282 MB of archives.
After this operation, 137 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 729339 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-gl-550-server_550.54.15-0ubuntu0.22.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-gl-550-server:amd64 (550.54.15-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-550-server_550.54.15-0ubuntu0.22.04.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-gpucomp.so.550.54.15', which is also in package libnvidia-compute-550:amd64 550.54.15-0ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-550-server_550.54.15-0ubuntu0.22.04.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I tried to change to the open driver via the GUI, but it refuses any changes. Also apt remove or even purge fail.
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices                                                                        
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00002783sv00001462sd00005138bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
driver   : nvidia-driver-550 - third-party non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-550-server-open - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-550-open - third-party non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-550-server - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin


Unfortunately, the way via the GUI was also not available, as APT also had problems with the broken package. The repair options in APT also refused to work. However, I then started Ubuntu using the repair mode (GRUB option "advanced boot options") and tried a few things here. Again, APT could not perform the repair with apt --fix-broken install.
But the "clean" option in the menu seems to have removed the broken package. After the reboot I was back on the correct driver version.

Try this:
hit the Win/Super key, begin typing 'Additional drivers'
... a greenish icon will show up quite soon, click on it.
Wait a minute or so and there will be lines showing up in the window.
Select any of the non-server versions of drivers (= installation attempt).
Reboot to verify that what you selected does indeed work.
A fail-safe option might be "nouveau" (often the last in the list).
Good luck.

The same problem on ubuntu-server. I need this driver for working with cuda. May be someone know how to fix it in console?
